# Unknown Job Issue: Ubuntu Upstart Conf though syntax is ok

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upstart, solr

I am trying to run Apache Solr 4.10.4 as service in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have written the following upstart conf file :

```
sudo vim /etc/init/my-solr-job.conf

# my-solr - Search Backend Engine

description "my solr search engine"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 3 60

env JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"

exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar /home/xyzuser/solr-4.10.4/example/start.jar
#Tried this also
#exec /home/xyzuser/solr-4.10.4/bin/solr -f -p 8983
```

When I run the following commands, I am getting these outputs:-

**Command 1**

```
init-checkconf -d /etc/init/my-solr.conf 
DEBUG: upstart_path=/sbin/init
DEBUG: initctl_path=/sbin/initctl
DEBUG: Setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/tmp/init-checkconf.zPFmEfcI7D'
DEBUG: Unsetting UPSTART_SESSION (unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-    session/1000/2037)
DEBUG: confdir=/tmp/init-checkconf.QFW9ZI7uGv
DEBUG: file=/etc/init/my-solr.conf
DEBUG: job=my-solr
DEBUG: upstart_out=/tmp/init-checkconf-upstart-output.ykMpMbTBU6
DEBUG: upstart_cmd=/sbin/init --user --no-dbus --no-startup-event --    verbose --confdir /tmp/init-checkconf.QFW9ZI7uGv
DEBUG: Upstart pid=5661
DEBUG: Joining Upstart session 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/5661'
DEBUG: Waiting for Upstart to initialise (attempt 1)
DEBUG: Secondary Upstart (/sbin/init --user --no-dbus --no-startup-    event --verbose --confdir /tmp/init-checkconf.QFW9ZI7uGv) running with PID 5661
File /etc/init/my-solr.conf: syntax ok
DEBUG: Restoring XDG_RUNTIME_DIR to '/run/user/1000'
DEBUG: Restoring UPSTART_SESSION to     'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/2037'
DEBUG: Stopping secondary Upstart (running with PID 5661)
```

**Command 2**

```
initctl check-config my-solr
initctl: Invalid job class: my-solr
```

**Command 3**

```
initctl list | grep my-solr
<Output is nothing. I tried using initctl reload-configuration>
```

**Command 4**

```
sudo service my-solr start
start: Unknown job: my-solr
```

**Command 5**

```
ln -s /etc/init/my-solr.conf /etc/init.d/my-solr
<Did not make any difference>
```

Can anybody help me out with this? I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I unset this env variable and it worked like a charm

```
env | grep UPSTART
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/2037
```

The command I used :

```
unset UPSTART_SESSION
```

But I still did not understand the root cause of it.

I modified conf file a little bit because when I was trying to stop the job, it was giving me - Unknown Instance error

Here is my final conf -

```
# my-solr - Search Backend Engine

description "my solr search engine"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 3 60

env JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"

exec /home/xyzuser/solr-4.10.4/bin/solr start -f -p 8983
pre-stop exec /home/xyzuser/solr-4.10.4/bin/solr stop -f -p 8983
```

I used pre-stop because stop was sending SIGTERM to the job, so using above I tried to stop the job gracefully.